# Google spreadsheets drop down not compatible with MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-docs, google-drive

I've created a drop down list on a google docs spreadsheet but when I download the spreadsheet and open it up under excel, the drop down functionality is lost and only the first item is shown.

I have also tried doing it backwards (first creating the drop down under excel and uploading it) with no success.

Also tried both ways, selecting from a range, or typing in your own range.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of suggestion? Like you said, it's not compatible. Were you hoping for some kind of work around that somehow makes docs compatible with Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, Google Docs isn't 100% compatible with MS Office. So of course some features in docs don't work correctly when you open them in Excel, and vice-versa. There isn't a whole lot you can do about this, it's something Google would have to fix.

You can, of course, upload the Excel file without converting it to Google Docs format. But then you won't be able to edit it online using Google Spreadsheets. If you really need an online editor that's fully compatible with Excel, you can use Microsoft's own cloud storage solution: [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/).

Comment: Old thread that was just bumped.  Microsoft's Office Online is now available.  The free version has some crippled functionality, so it would require verifying that all of the required features are enabled.  But to the extent that it has the features, it's virtually 100% compatible with the MS Office desktop software.